# vbTab \ Chr(9) Writing New Line in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I am attempting to convert Word tables into paragraph text via VBA. I know about `Convert to Text` option for tables, but this is not working as my Word files are converted PDF files that have images which eventually will get processed through Python script. The tables have no reliable and consistent use of tab, para, or anything else when converted.

My code follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReWriteTableData()

    Dim tb As Table

    For Each tb In ThisDocument.Tables

        tb.Select

        With Selection

            Dim rw As row, cl As Column
            Dim i As Integer

            .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

            For Each rw In tb.Rows

                .EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                .TypeParagraph

                For i = 1 To tb.Columns.Count

                    Dim myText As String, myString As String
                    myString = rw.Cells(i).Range.Text
                    myString = Mid(myString, 1, Len(myString) - 1)

                    .TypeText Text:=myString & Chr(9)

                Next

            Next

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

The place where I am stuck is `.TypeText Text:=myString & Chr(9)`.

When that prints the text to the line above the table it places the 2nd - nth column on a new line, like this:

---

[image]

---

What I want is this:

[image]

I know pictures are slightly incomplete, but the loop isn't my issue, it's getting them all on one line. Also, I am sure my code is not the most efficient, so am happy to have any refactor to make it faster, easier, better to maintain.

Comment: Could you click on `Show paragraph marks` in MS Word app and next paste your images again showing the real structure of document (with all hidden marks)? Just for better understanding...

Comment: @TimWilliams - that did it! I'm going kind of crazy because I thought I already changed the `-1` to `-2`. Quick (hopefully) follow-up question? Is there a way to use that end-of-cell character in `Convert-To-Text`?

Comment: Well I'm glad it worked but you may notice I'd deleted my comment in the meantime, since I was having second thoughts...   Are you sure there wasn't some other character lurking at the end of your cell text, just before the end of cell marker?  **EDIT** OK it is two characters it seems: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/2005-10/msg00121.html

Comment: Thanks again @TimWilliams